# Request laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

espero me puedan ayudar.
Tengo un menú donde pongo agrego la clase active de acuerdo al request, algo así:

```
<li @if(request()->is('asistencias') || request()->is('asistenciasHistorico') ) class="active text-right" @endif><a href="{{ url('asistencias') }}" class="list-group-item">Asistencias</a></li>
```

Pero al editar un usuario lo hago por get, por ejemplo: http://127.0.0.1:8000/usuario/99 esa es la URL de la edición de la información del ID 99 el problema es que no se ideo una forma para detectar esa URL y poder cambiar la clase active de editar usuario en mi menú y funcione para todos los id's.

Gracias

Comment: como tienes tu controlador? me es raro ese @if no entiendo el porque, si a la vista le dejas ese tipo de trabajo no es la mejor opcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencillo, en tu vista, haz lo siguiente, tomando en cuenta que tu url contiene la palabra "usuario":

```
<li class="{{ request()->is('usuario/*') || request()->is('usuario') ? 'active' : '' }}"></li>
```

Aquí hago uso del operador ternario `?`, quiere decir que si en la url contiene la palabra "usuario" o si contiene "usuario/*" (el * significa cualquier palabra o letra que le siga a la diagonal) agregará la clase `active`, de lo contrario no agregará algo, también lo puedes hacer con tus condicionales `if` si gustas...

**NOTA:**

No sé si tu forma de agregar la clase `active` sea la mejor forma de hacerlo pero yo lo que normalmente hago es que agrego un `@yield('entidad_active')` en cada `<li>` (o cualquier etiqueta que utilices) del menú en la plantilla padre, de esta manera en la plantilla hijo pondrías un

```
@section('entidad_active') 
active 
@endsection
```

dependiendo de la sección en la que te encuentres y listo, no tendría que hacer las validaciones en cada sección del menú...